# Google Drive Picker: Show only top level folders

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker

Currently I am using `google.picker.​ViewId.FOLDERS` view in Google drive picker. This however, shows all the folders(including deep level folders) in my drive.

How to achieve a view in which only the top level folders are displayed at first? This would be similar to Dropbox chooser's file view.

Comment: you could use ".addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setParent('root').setIncludeFolders(true))". This will show the elements at root level, although it will show files as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. However, it seems that the search doesn't search in deep levels after applying this. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: your are right. try this one .addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(true)). I was able to search files in deep levels

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly now. This solution should be the final answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to see the folders and files at root level, you can use the view: `addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(true))`

You will be able to search for items in deeper levels.

Comment: Per google documentation: "Do not combine with setOwnedByMe. When setIncludeFolders(true) is set, setOwnedByMe is ignored.

Answer (score 9):

For reference. This works fine now:

```js
 let docsView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS)
                            .setParent('root')
                            .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);
```